# The set of predecessors of a node in a tree is finite?

Tags: relations, order-theory, trees, ordinals

I came across the following definitions of *tree* and *transitive tree*, respectively, in the book *Modal Logic* by P. Blackburn:

**Definition 1.** A *tree* is a relational structure $(T, R)$, where:

1. $T$, the set of nodes, contains a unique $r \in T$ (the *root*) st
   $$\forall t \in T\, (rR^*t), $$
   where $R^*$ is the *reflexive transitive closure* of $R$.
2. Every element of $T$ distinct from $r$ has a unique $R$-predecessor. (This is literally what the definition says. I assume it actually means there is a unique maximal element that precedes $t$)
3. $R$ is acyclic.

**Definition 2.** A *transitive tree* is a strict partial order $(T,<)$ st:

1. There is a *root r* satisfying that if $t\neq r $, then $r<t$.
2. The set $\{s\in T: s<t\}$ of predecessors of $t$ is linearly ordered and finite.

Immediately after the second definition, there is the following

**Problem.** If $(T,S)$ is a tree, then $(T,S^+)$ is a transitive tree, where $S^+$ is the *transitive closure* of $S$.

My question is about the cardinality of the set of predecessors with the given definition. In particular, let us take $T=\omega+1$, and $S$ the inverted order given to the ordinal numbers, i.e. $$\alpha S \beta \iff \beta < \alpha$$

where $<$ is the usual order for ordinal numbers: $\beta <\alpha$ iff $\beta\in \alpha$.

My assertion is that this is a counterexample of the problem, since

1. $S=S^+$, for $S$ is already transitive.
2. $\omega$ is the root of $(T,S)$.
3. Every element $\alpha \in T$ different from its root has a unique maximal predecessor, namely $\alpha +1$.
4. $S$ is acyclic.
5. For any $\alpha$, the set $\{\beta\in T:\beta S\alpha\}=\{\beta\in T:\alpha<\beta\}$ is infinite.

Thus, $(T,S)$ is a "tree" (according to this definition, because of 2, 3 and 4), but not a "transitive tree", because of 1 and 5.

Did I misunderstand something? Is that actually a counterexample? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I think you are correct. That is, if I'm not missing anything. Given the question in the title and the definitions, I mentally came up with the counter-example: $\{0\}\cup\{1/n:n\geq1\}$ with the order inherited from $\mathbb Q$; notice this is order-isomorphic to your's.